# accessing property of potential null/undefined variable - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sonarqube

i'm analyzing my code using sonarqube and am running into an issue with the following code:

```
var backtoyear = $('#backtoyear').val();

if (backtoyear != undefined || backtoyear.length > 0) {
   var currentyear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
   var numberofyears = currentyear - backtoyear;
}
```

the `backtoyear.length` variable is causing an "TypeError can be thrown as "backtoyear" might be null or undefined here." because it could potential be null/undefined and therefore won't have any properties.

should i just remove the second have of the OR from the if condition?

Comment: I suspect the `||` should be `&&`; the second expression should not be attempted if `backtoyear` actually is `undefined`.

Comment: To detect `undefined`, you should use `typeof` as shown here  `if (typeof backtoyear !== undefined || backtoyear.length > 0) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your following statement,

```
if (backtoyear != undefined || backtoyear.length > 0) {
```

to

```
if (backtoyear) {
```

This is more readable, efficient and understandable.

Refer to this specification [ToBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toboolean)

Comment: i really like this simplification. however, i wish to understand a little better. by just doing `if (backtoyear)` this checks it can't be null or undefined, and that the length also is greater than (and not equal to) 0?

Comment: @testing yes it checks for null, undefined and length as well, coz if it is null or undefined then logically it has no length.